# Django @login_required for class views

Tags: django-views, python-decorators, login-required

I inherited a Django(1.5.1) project and I need to put one view behind a `@login_required` decorator.  Here is what i have in `views.py`:

I got this snippet of code from [here](http://brack3t.com/our-custom-mixins.html) and it looks like its purpose is to allow someone to apply the `@login_required`decorator to a `class`

```
class LoginRequiredMixin(object):
    """
    View mixin which verifies that the user has authenticated.

    NOTE:
        This should be the left-most mixin of a view.
    """

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)


class PermissionRequiredMixin(object):
    login_url = settings.LOGIN_URL
    permission_required = None
    raise_exception = False
    redirect_field_name = '/workers/'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Verify class settings
        if self.permission_required == None or len(
            self.permission_required.split(".")) != 2:
            raise Error("'PermissionRequiredMixin' requires "
                "'permission_required' attribute to be set.")

        has_permission = request.user.has_perm(self.permission_required)

        if not has_permission:
            if self.raise_exception:
                return HttpResponseForbidden()
            else:
                path = urlquote(request.get_full_path())
                tup = self.login_url, self.redirect_field_name, path
                return HttpResponseRedirect("%s?%s=%s" % tup)

        return super(PermissionRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(
            request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I then apply this to the view i want to add permissions to like so:

```
class RootWorkerView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, APIView):
    renderer_classes = (WorkersJSONRenderer, JSONRenderer,
                        BrowsableAPIRenderer)

    def get(self, request):
        worker_list = rest_models.WorkerList(request)
        serializer = WorkerListSerializer(worker_list)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

The `APIView` argument is a carry over, as before it was the only argument.  Is this correct?

When run, I get nothing.  The template for the view I want to secure shows up with no login prompt.

Relevant snippet from `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^workers/$', views.RootWorkerView.as_view(),
    name='root_worker_view'),

url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login',
    {'template_name': 'dashboard/login.html'}),
```

`/login/` does work, and I can login successful, so that's not the issue.

I feel like `@method_decorator(login_required)` isnt doing its job.  Any ideas?

Comment: I haven't taken a terribly close look at what you're doing. But I think usually the login_required is applied for class views via the url definitions. It is, after all, just a function. You can wrap like so `login_required(MyClassView.as_view())`

Comment: @Paul_R That is an interesting idea, I will give that a shot today and see how it goes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can add the decorator in the urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
 url(r'^workers/$', login_required(views.RootWorkerView.as_view()))
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Also if you need to put parameter login_url of this decorator you can write like that: url(r'^workers/$', login_required(login_url='')(views.RootWorkerView.as_view()))

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek Your code is not working.

Answer (score 10):

now you can use Django builtin LoginRequiredMixin

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin